# Cannot execute Python script from Java in different directories

Tags: java, python, cmd

I am trying to execute a **python script from java** which script is in a different directory.

I am calling the following code from Java:

```
private final String PATH_TO_PREDICTIONS_SCRIPT = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Final Year Project\\Documentation\\Predictive Model\\Prediction Model ~ v0.4 10-03-2018\\predictions.py";

public TrainTestResults() throws IOException {

    initComponents();  //JFrame

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python " + this.PATH_TO_PREDICTIONS_SCRIPT);

}
```

This python script will save a file with some results in the directory specified which I will read from Java later on.

I am sure it has something to do with the directory formatting as when I execute python scripts from the **cmd** I have to do this if working in a different directory:

```
os.chdir(r'path')
```

Any help on how to do this straight away from the Java runtime process and without moving the files into the same directory would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: use absolute path in python file

Comment: Okay I figured it out. Turns out that the python script was reading a file from its directory and saving the new file in its directory as I put only readfile and writefile names and not the full directory when reading and writing in the script. Therefore, the java runtime process was expecting the readfile to be in the java directory.